# pdf remove javascript

Tags: php

A user sent me a PDF that contains javascript. I would like to remove the Javascript to prevent possible attacks. Can I remove the Javascript using PHP or by another method? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You're really going to need to clarify your question if you want any sort of helpful answer. What are you trying to do?

Comment: just write a js through PHP coding or something to do that :P

Comment: Best-guess translation: *"A user sent me a PDF that contains javascript. I would like to remove the Javascript to prevent possible attacks. Can I remove the Javascript using PHP or by another method? Any suggestion is appreciated."*

Answer (score 2):

First, to prevent possible attacks, you can disable javascript processing in Acrobat entirely. The method varies according to your version, but one such step-by-step guide can be found here: http://egyptianvulture.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-disable-javascript-in-acrobat.html

To remove javascript entirely from PDF documents programatically will take some research, unfortunately I can't offer any advice here except to search online. (I did so, and the results are sparse.)

You can remove javascript using a 3rd party application, such as [Quick PDF Tools Pro](http://www.quickpdftools.com/), which is a $59 application. I don't know how successful it is, nor can I recommend it, but it is advertised as a feature. *Caution:* Password-protected PDF files likely will prevent such removal.